# Is there is pandas error or I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

This is the code that is raising keyError

```
most_valued_category = df.groupby('Category').Value.sum().reset_index()
print(most_valued_category)
```

Error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-5b310cd40031> in <module>
----> 1 most_valued_category = df.groupby('Category').Value.sum().reset_index()
 2 print(most_valued_category)
 KeyError: "Category"
```

When I looked into the info of dataFrame look what it shows

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 216930 entries, 0 to 216929
Data columns (total 7 columns):
#   Column       Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------       --------------   ----- 
0   Show Number  216930 non-null  int64 
1    Air Date    216930 non-null  object
2    Round       216930 non-null  object
3    Category    216930 non-null  object
4    Value       216930 non-null  object
5    Question    216930 non-null  object
6    Answer      216928 non-null  object
dtypes: int64(1), object(6)
memory usage: 11.6+ MB
```

None

Comment: Check to see if the column 'Category' exist in your DataFrame.

Comment: What are the columns in your ``df`` variable?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your Category column has a space in front of it, together with some of the other columns. To fix it, you can run this code after creating the dataframe.

```
df.colums = [name.strip() for name in df.columns]
```

This will remove all leading and trailing whitespace from all colums.

Answer (score 0):

It normally means that there is a misspell in the key -name of the column- you are calling; in this case the "Category" key you are using.

By reviewing the data frame information on column name and type, there seems to be no error, unless there is a leading or trailing space in the name " Category" or "Category ". The other possibility is that you are using '' instead of "".

Also be wary because the type of the column "Category" is of the type Object and not number, so it will probably send a new error once you clear the "name/key" error and try to sum.

Answer (score 0):

*ScootCork* only **supposed** that your *Category* column has an initial
space.

From your post I see that the problem is more serious: **all** your colums,
except the first, **do** have such an initial space.

Look at your printout from *df.info()*, where all column names are **left aligned**:

```
0   Show Number  ...
1    Air Date    ...
2    Round       ...
3    Category    ...
4    Value       ...
5    Question    ...
6    Answer      ...
```

Do you see that all column names, except the first, are 1 place shifted
right? This means that all of them have just this initial space.

The most probable reason is that:

- You read this file using e.g. *read_csv*, with column names in the
  first row,
- This first row is formatted something like `Show Number, Air Date, Round,`  and so on.

For a human these spaces (after each comma) are meaningless, they even
cause that reading is easier.
But *read_csv* just splits this row by commas, hence all "further" columns
have just this initial space.

The remedy is to **drop** these spaces from your CSV file.

Another option is to add *skipinitial-space=True* parameter to *read_csv*,
but this option pertains to **all** input rows, not only the header row.